# Как написать сортировку массива объектов методом прямой вставки?

Tags: c#, массивы, сортировка

Имеется класс с такими полями и конструктором соответственно:

```
public Pretendent(string famil, string nameotch, string years, string rost, 
   string glaza, string hairs, string zp, string kvartira, string car)
    {...
```

Создается массив объектов класса в который вводятся данные из текстбоксов:

```
List<Pretendent> pretend = new List<Pretendent>();
pretend.Add(new Pretendent(textBox3.Text,...
```

Так вот, нужно создать отдельный класс с методом который будет сортировать этот массив методом прямой вставки по полю years.

Comment: и в чем возникла проблема?

Comment: Непонятно, откуда взялось странное требование «методом прямой вставки». Это учебное задание, что ли?